# Jenkins Build with Parameters using Cucumber-JVM

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, cucumber-jvm

I was wondering if anyone here has ever used Jenkins with Cucumber-JVM and built their project using Build with Parameters plugin. Is it possible to pass parameters along to the steps definitions through Jenkins using the Build with Parameters plugin?

**EDIT**

Ok, with Cucumber you have a feature file where you can have a data table when using a Scenario Outline with Examples. That data gets passed to the placeholder which then gets passed to your parameterized method. I'm trying to understand how I would go about coding this with Jenkins or if it's even possible.

Comment: Should be easy to pass argumets since it has a [CLI Runner](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#cli-runner). In its current stats i consider that question a bit broad.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work. Does anyone have any experience setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of people changing data on scenario outlines through Jenkins parameters but I haven't tried to either.  You would need Jenkins to act as a macro pre-processor to make all the substitutions.  And it sounds like you would need a lot of parameters.

A different approach may be to use Java [properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) files. Your java code can read the properties files and fill in objects that your steps then run with.  Scenario outline data tables can be used to create List and Map objects (see [here](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables)).  Instead of specifying the data in scenario outline tables, have the step read a properties file to populate the objects. Different property files can be deployed into different environments.

This assumes that you really need this kind of flexibility which static cucumber doesn't provide. A nice touch would be to print out what the scenario outline data tables would have looked like.